# PHP & MongoDB - Querying Array

Tags: php, mongodb

I can do a bounding box location query fine, like this:

```
$cursor = $coll->find(array('loc' => array('$within' => array('$box' => $box))));
```

And another basic query works:

```
$cursor = $coll->find(array('type' => $filter));
```

But when I try to combine both into a new query, it's not working:

```
$cursor = $coll->find(array(

    array('loc' => array('$within' => array('$box' => $box))), 

    array('type' => $filter)

));
```

Am I handling the query string incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is not correct, you should simply do:

```
$cursor = $coll->find(array(
    'loc' => array('$within' => array('$box' => $box)),
    'type' => $filter,
));
```

Ie, have one array with all the query parts.